# C# What does using the [System.Diagnostics.Conditional] attribute on an attribute class actually do

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've known about using the conditional attribute on methods for a while now, but I just found out that it can also be used on attribute classes, so I wrote some code to test it, but its not performing as expected.

This MSDN page shows how to use the conditional attribute on an attribute class down the bottom of the page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xssyw96%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.

I'm using the Unity engine by the way. I don't think that should matter, but it might I guess.

Here's the test code I wrote:

```
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("UNITY_EDITOR")]
public class TestAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string text;

    public TestAttribute(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Test("This shouldn't exist on android")]
    public void Awake()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        Debug.Log("This only gets logged in the Unity Editor, not in an Android build");
#endif

        Debug.Log("Begin Attribute Test");
        {
            object[] attributes = typeof(NewBehaviourScript).GetMethod("Awake").GetCustomAttributes(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log(attributes[i]);// This logs TestAttribute both in the editor and on android.
            }

            TestAttribute att = attributes[0] as TestAttribute;
            Debug.Log(att.text);// This logs "This shouldn't exist on android" both in the editor and on android.
        }
        Debug.Log("End Attribute Test");
        Debug.Log("");
        Debug.Log("Begin Method Test");
        {
            Method();// This only gets called in the Unity Editor, as expected from the conditional attribute.

            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(NewBehaviourScript).GetMethod("Method");
            Debug.Log(methodInfo);// this logs "void Method()" both in the editor and on android.
        }
        Debug.Log("End Method Test");
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("UNITY_EDITOR")]
    public void Method()
    {
        Debug.Log("This shouldn't exist on android either");
    }
}
```

If the conditional attribute doesn't stop GetCustomAttributes() from getting the test attribute, what does it actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article, the Conditional Attribute prevents the compiler from emitting MSIL for a `void` returning function for which the stated condition does not exist.

I think that your first use of it is trying to tell the system that the TestAttribute attribute shouldn't exist if the condition isn't met, which doesn't seem to be what it's for.

When you are getting the MethodInfo for method `Method` later on, I think that the compiler has generated the call to `Method`, but it should not perform any action because there is no code to be performed. (i.e. the method should immediately return.)

You don't actually seem to be calling `Method`, just getting info about it, which I think could be misleading you.

Comment: Look at the last section in the link I provided. The conditional attribute is allowed to be placed on attribute classes, so logically one should be able to assume that it achieves something when you put it there. I'll try invoking the method info and see if it logs anything.

Comment: OK, so invoking the method info does run the method normally. The conditional attribute doesn't stop the method from existing, it just strips out the actual calls. But then what does putting the conditional attribute on a class do? The class still exists and can be used normally.

Comment: The documentation you listed only covers VS versions up to 2008. The info on Conditional for later versions doesn't say anything about using it on Attribute classes. It's possible that either 1) the behaviour has changed or 2) the original documentation was incorrect.

Comment: I think if the class just stopped existing on the basis of Conditional it would cause a lot of headaches all over the place. (Like the runtime not being able to find things which may have been known about at compile time). Just NOPing a method out is trivial compared to this.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. The metadata for the conditional attribute shows that it still allows attribute usage on both classes and methods, and if I put the conditional attribute on a non-attribute class (like NewBehaviourScript in my example), the compiler throws an error: "error CS1689: Attribute `System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute' is only valid on methods or attribute classes". It could be that you're right, but I would have expected to see an obsolete warning or something if that were the case.

Comment: Also, that page you linked has a short paragraph under remarks about using the conditional attribute for a class.

Comment: Yeah, it says it can be used on a class as long as the class derives from Attribute. It doesn't, however, say that it actually does anything when applied this way. This, again, leads me to believe that it no longer performs what they had intended it to do in the first place but they've left some of the behaviour behind so that it doesn't break on people. Although I would have hoped, had that been the case, that they would have put in a compiler warning or something.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're probably right. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

Let me simplify your example:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
class MyAttribute : Attribute {}

[MyAttribute]
class MyClass {}
```

When the `Conditional` attribute is applied to an `Attribute`-derived type, it causes the attribute to be removed from *all marked symbols* if the `Conditional` attribute's condition does not hold. So in the example above, `MyClass` is marked with `MyAttribute` in debug builds only; in Release builds, the `DEBUG` symbol is not defined (usually, at least), so the compiler removes `[MyAttribute]` from the declaration of `MyClass`. You can see that when using reflection, try to run the following code in debug and release builds:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var attribute = typeof(MyClass).GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>();
    Console.WriteLine(attribute == null ? "missing" : "exists");
}
```

This will print "exists" in debug builds and "missing" in release builds. However, only the *application* of the attribute is removed; the attribute class itself still exists in the compiled assembly. This is similar to how `Conditional` works for methods: Only the method invocations are removed, the methods still exist and can be called via reflection, for instance.

Why can that be useful? One use case is described by [JetBrains](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/) in a blog post (see section "The JetBrains.Annotations NuGet package"): They have a NuGet package called `JetBrains.Annotations` that contains various attributes that help their tool Resharper to analyze C# code. Adding this NuGet package to your project, however, would require you to ship that assembly with your product, even though you only really use it for coding; not at runtime. So what they do is: They annotate all attributes in the assembly with the `Conditional` attribute. This causes the compiler to strip out the attributes during compilation; it then notices that `JetBrains.Annotations` is never referenced, removing the reference from the compiled assembly. Consequently, you do not have to ship JetBrains' assembly with your product.

I have no idea, however, if this is working in Unity at all. Unity is known to use an old version of Mono and the C# compiler, so maybe there are bugs preventing all of this from working. Actually, your code seems to show that this is indeed not working correctly in Unity. But if you run my or your code in a standalone .NET application, it works. By the way, you can also use newer versions of the C# compiler to compile assemblies that Unity can then reference; that should allow you to work around this issue in Unity.

**Update 2018-03-17**: The latest versions of Unity now feature a newer Mono runtime and an updated C# compiler (and will update to Microsofts C# compiler soon). So any non-standard behavior regarding conditionally compiled-in attributes should be fixed in the latest versions of Unity.

Comment: I just did a test and found that Unity actually gives the expected behaviour when putting MyAttribute on a class (the attribute isn't there outside debug mode), but not when putting it on a method or property as I was in my example.

Comment: I might be necroing a post but it's important to note that unity functions such as awake and update are called via reflection.